# What is the javascript `window.Notation` object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I was playing around in the chrome developer console, and found the `Notation` member of window. However, it's native code, and any invocation seems to throw `TypeError: Illegal constructor`. It doesn't seem to be present in IE10.

What is this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Notation)

> NOTE: This is not implemented in Mozilla
>
> **Represents a DTD notation (read-only)**. May declare format of an
>   unparsed entity or formally declare the document's processing
>   instruction targets. Inherits methods and properties from Node. Its
>   nodeName is the notation name. Has no parent.

The [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-5431D1B9) explains why any constructor call fails :

> The DOM Core does not support editing Notation nodes; they are
>   therefore readonly.

I'm not sure this still makes a lot of sense now that the web is largely going away frow XML and XHTML...